# How to analyse Jovian signal received at 20.1 MHz using dual dipole antenna?

Tags: amateur-observing, radio-astronomy

I have purchased a [Radio Jove](https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/software/) kit and set it up. I have also received some signals. I am using [Radio Skypipe II](http://www.radiosky.com/skypipeishere.html) software as discussed in this Radio Jove [tutorial](https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/data_analysis/data_tutorial.htm) (see also [here](http://www.reeve.com/Documents/Articles%20Papers/Reeve_RSPSoundcardSetup.pdf)) with a sound card to record and analyze the output of the receiver.

But what I get is like an image on the screen, which can be zoomed, and I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

What further process should I follow to make some analysis of Jovian radio signals at 20.1 MHz beyond just looking at the image ([spectrogram? waterfall plot?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_plot)) that the software produces?

Here is an example of the Radio Skypipe II output from their [link](http://www.radiosky.com/skypipeishere.html):

[image: Radio Skypipe II example output]

Comment: Can you take a spectrum somehow? Or is the kit limited to one wavelength-band?

Comment: You need to clarify what you consider a "proper analysis" and what output you get (in what form) from this setup.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape have added links...

Comment: @SHANKARPRASADMITRA can you add a screen shot of the image you are seeing? That would be a big help, thanks! I have a very old Radio Jove as well, but so far I've never put it together. I'm really interested in hearing about your experience!

Comment: You could try looking at spectral analysis (FFT), but it sounds like you've got a new toy and don't have any specific task in mind.  Is there something in particular you were hoping to achieve?

Comment: Analyzing and identifying signals in the radio spectrum is an actual profession that involves months of training plus specialized tools and documentation. This question does not provide even the tiniest fraction of the details necessary to identify a specific signal.

Comment: If you have the paid version of sky pipe you can export the signal into an ASCII file and then write scripts for further processing.